# nokogiri how to get text in ul , li , div and strong

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

how to get the text "cccc"

this is html :

```
<ul id="tt">
  <li id="tt-xx"><div class="dt">aa:</div><div class="dd"><span>123</span></div></li>
  <li id="tt-aa">
    <div class="dt">xx</div>
    <div class="dd">
      <strong class="cc_aa" id="ee_aa">cccc</strong>
      <a id="f" clstag="a|b|c">zz</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

so , how to get that text "cccc" ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML '<ul id="tt">
  <li id="tt-xx"><div class="dt">aa:</div><div class="dd"><span>123</span></div></li>
  <li id="tt-aa">
    <div class="dt">xx</div>
    <div class="dd">
      <strong class="cc_aa" id="ee_aa">cccc</strong>
      <a id="f" clstag="a|b|c">zz</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>'

doc.at_css('#ee_aa').text
```